# Ajax Data Call with or without slash in Codeigniter getting error

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

suppose my URL is **example.com/controller/method/**

when I use this ajax code it makes URL like **example.com/controller/method/method** which not getting data.

```
    function getProductList() {
    var category = document.getElementById('Category').value;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'GetProductList',
        data: {CategoryId: category},
        dataType: 'json',
        cache:false,
        success: function (response) {

        }
    });
}
```

but when my URL is **example.com/controller/method**   then ajax getting data correctly. but i want to get data from the database on both situations.

Comment: In my knowledge code Ignitor doesn't *example.com/controller/method/method*

Comment: this URL made by ajax when my page URL: example.com/controller/method/ and i try to get something from example.com/controller/another_method/  then ajax make url example.com/controller/method/another_method may you understand

Answer (score 0):

Typically there is a one-to-one relationship between a URL string and its corresponding controller class/method. So you can not use **example.com/controller/method/method**.The segments in a URI normally follow this pattern: **example.com/class/function/id/** , So your last method argument treated as a id. so create method in controller with the default argument **Ex. `public function mymethod($method = ''){ /** Your logic goes here */ }`**